# What's next in this letter sequence: B, C, N, O

Tags: letter-sequence

What would come next in this sequence, and what is the source?

> B C N O

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> F

Reason:

> B, C, N, O, F are the atomic symbols of the periodic table, in order, of Boron, Carbon, Nitrogen, Oxygen and Fluorine.

Comment: yup! pretty easy one, but it wasn't a sequence I recognized off the top of my head so I thought i'd put it out there.

Comment: @DLeh But it was a very good one!

Comment: what about 'Y'? BC+10+NO+10 = Y

Comment: @DLeh It could also be Z as the distance between C & N are 10 characters so skip 10 characters after **O** and you will get the leter ***Z***